# WSO2 Identity Server 5.1 management console customizing is not functioning

Tags: server, wso2, identity

I tried to replace WSO2 Identity Server logo with my company logo in Main.Css file of corresponding jar.

But when I tried to restart the server the Jar file is not loading. Even if it is loading the logo is not getting displayed.

Any replies?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have changed the jar and replaced the existing one in repository/components/plugins folder. If so, this gets replaced by the original jars in repository/components/patches/patch0000 folder.

If this is the case what you can do is create a folder such as patch5000 in the patches folder and place the modified jar in it and restart. Let me know if this works.